# Is it possible to have dynamic typing based on object properties?

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following structure:

```
type ErrorObject = {
  name: string,
  message: string,
}

const ALL_ERRORS: ErrorObject[] = [
   {
     name: 'No-empty-name',
     message: 'You must provide a name',
   },
   {
     name: 'No-empty-age',
     message: 'You must provide an age',
   },
   {
     name: 'No-under-18',
     message: 'You must be 18+ to continue',
   }
]
```

---

Now I'm trying to create a type which would define all the possible error `name`s, that should end up like this:

```
type PossibleErrorNames = 'No-empty-name' | 'No-empty-age' | 'No-under-18'
```

*This would work alright, but in my actual project, obviously the array is much larger and it feels super sluggish to update both types, as they would have a dependancy on each other (if you update one, you have to update the other).*

---

I tried the following:

```
const ALL_NAMES = ALL_ERRORS.map(err => `'${err.name}'`).join(' | ')
type PossibleErrorNames = ALL_NAMES
```

Issue here is, this is incorrect, as this would `ALL_NAMES` returns as

`"'No-empty-name' | 'No-empty-age' | 'No-under-18'"` which is a `string`.

---

Obviously, this is the expected behaviour of `join()`, but is there a way I could either

1. **Turn the string into an expression**
2. **Some perhaps more elegant name to infer the types from the `ALL_ERRORS` array?**

Comment: No, `.join` and other array manipulation happens *at runtime*. There is no type system at runtime, it ceases to exist at compile time. You *can* have an array as a type, but it has to be transformable at compile time, so `["a", "b", "c"]` can be turned to `"a" | "b" | "c"` but `for (const string of something) arr.push(string)` isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [as const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and do something like this, provided that the full array is known at compile time.

```
type ErrorObject = {
  name: string,
  message: string
}


const ALL_ERRORS = [
   {
     name: 'No-empty-name',
     message: 'You must provide a name',
   },
   {
     name: 'No-empty-age',
     message: 'You must provide an age',
   },
   {
     name: 'No-under-18',
     message: 'You must be 18+ to continue',
   }
] as const // <----- notice here

type PossibleErrorNames = typeof ALL_ERRORS[number]["name"]
// "No-empty-name" | "No-empty-age" | "No-under-18"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.5.1&ssl=22&ssc=6&pln=22&pc=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nA8gIwFYQMbCgXigG8BYAKCigDsBDAWwgC4oBnYOASyoHMAacygxYsa3Jq3Zdu5AL7l5ZbIipsoAQQAyGgPowASnpR6AygSgBtAZVIVKlWg2YByAHKIAtBDphQ7hxCd+WzshETFnAE1EAFcoOmjVMCQANw4AE2gaanoAoLsZPOsrO39nN09vX1Fc4sEIYWrImLiEvCTEVIyoGipusUDiguKbO3scso9oqgy4dwBGAA4B4LqG8KgnKNj41TRoRYBqKGBEKCUqYC5omuC5MgBdbpYz5TYFUEgoAAVEYQ40AA2EHgSDgLhyz0IHwgiAAZuotLoDEZjOYqNE6Hs4PdzAAify4+5AA)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to flip your list of all errors into an object, which will allow you to access the types at compile time. You can do this as follows:

```js
const AllErrors = {
  'No-empty-name': 'You must provide a name',
  'No-empty-age': 'You must provide an age',
  'No-under-18': 'You must be 18+ to continue',
}

// Rationalises to this: type AllErrorNames = "No-empty-name" | "No-empty-age" | "No-under-18"
type AllErrorNames = keyof typeof AllErrors

// And if you still need them in an array, you can use something like this
const AllErrorsArray = Object.keys(AllErrors).map(errorName => ({name: errorName, message: AllErrors[errorName]}))
```

Comment: I do correct myself, @bugs answer is the other only way ;), const assertions are new to me! Use their answer if you wish to keep your code as close to it is now!