# Typescript: valueof field of an array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

Is there a way to define a type by the values of a field in an array?

To simplify my question...
Given that I have a static array:

```
const arr = [
  {name: 'cat', language: 'meow'},
  {name: 'dog', language: 'bark'},
  {name: 'cow', language: 'moo'}
]
```

And I want to be able to create a function that gets the language based on the name field defined like so

```
function getLanguage(name: X) {
```

What can I define the type `X` to be so that I can limit X (the parameter of that function) to be any of the name fields in that list of objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have dynamic typing based on object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825981/is-it-possible-to-have-dynamic-typing-based-on-object-properties)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const arr = [
  {name: 'cat', language: 'meow'},
  {name: 'dog', language: 'bark'},
  {name: 'cow', language: 'moo'}
] as const // pay attention here

type Name = (typeof arr)[number]['name']; // evaluates into 'cat' | 'dog' | 'cow'

function getLanguage(name: Name) { }
```

Few things to understand:

- `as const` in order to say to TS that type should be narrowed to exact values
- `(typeof arr)[number]` - it gives as array element type, as `number` is a key of array mapped type
- `(typeof arr)[number]['name']` - it gives type of `name` field of array element type

If you don't need to narrow the type and `string` satisfy you for the name field then simply not append `as const`, in result `(typeof arr)[number]['name']` will be evaluated to `string` type.